# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'clip' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U41'), dtype('<U41'), dtype('<U41')) -> dtype('<U41')

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have got error when using `cv2_imshow` from `google colab`.
The code I tried is:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
def img(path):
    cv2_imshow(path)
```

But this throws the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 for file in np.hstack((human_files[:3], dog_files[:3])):
>   ----> 2     run_app(file)
>
> 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py
>   in _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting(ufunc, out, casting, *args, **kwargs)
>        83     # try to deal with broken casting rules
>        84     try:
>   ---> 85         return ufunc(*args, out=out, **kwargs)
>        86     except _exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError as e:
>        87         # Numpy 1.17.0, 2019-02-24
>
> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'clip' did not contain a loop with signature
>   matching types (dtype('
>   dtype('

Help!!

Comment: 'U41' is a unicode string, the default string type in Py3.  You have, apparently, provided a text array or file to this function.

Comment: yea , i printed type was numpy str , how do i change to Py3